# Cannot read "path" property of undefined Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, logging, upload

Here is my jade file

```
form(method="post", action="/upload", enctype="multipart/form-data")
      input(type="file", name="logName")
      button(type="submit") Upload
```

And my index.js file

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('fileUpload', { title: 'Building a Log File Viewer' });

});

var formidable = require('formidable'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util');

/* POST the file upload */
router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

        fs.readFileSync(files.upload.path, function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;

          console.log("Test");
           })
    });
});
```

I keep getting the TypeError property that property "path" is undefined; however, when I sumbit the code under a http.createServer, instead of a router.post, it works fine. I have also tried the asychronous file reading, and it gave me the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try

`fs.readFileSync(files.logName.path, function (err, data){ ... });`

instead of

`fs.readFileSync(files.upload.path, function (err, data) { ... });`

Comment: Nevermind, that worked. I had to replace the readFileSync with its asychononous type. Thanks!